# How to trigger a function from another component in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import { copilot, walkthroughable, CopilotStep } from 'react-native-copilot';
 class DashboardContent extends Component {
  state ={
    secondStepActive: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.start()
    this.props.copilotEvents.on('stepChange', this.handleStepChange);
  
  }
  
  handleStepChange = step => {
    console.log(`Current step is: ${step.name}`);
  };
   
  render() {
    
    return (
      <View>  ......   <View/>
           
    );
  }
}

export default copilot({
  animated: true, 
  overlay: 'svg', 
})(DashboardContent);
```

I am using the [react-native-copilot](https://github.com/mohebifar/react-native-copilot) library for a walkthrough. I wish to trigger the this.props.start() function which starts the walkthrough using a button from my NavBar component - The _infoPage function in the code below should trigger the function basicaly.

The code for the Navbar is :

```
class NavBar extends Component {

    state ={
        isModalVisible: false,
        email:'',
        emailError: false,
        emailErrorMessage: '',
    };

    _profileEdit() {
        Actions.profileedit();
      }
      _notificationsPage(){
          Actions.notifications();
      }
      _infoPage = () =>{
          this.props.toggleTour();
      }
      toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible});
      };

         
     render() {
       const {index, routes} = this.props.tabs;

           
       
       console.log(index);
       return (
        <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar />
            
            
                
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._infoPage}>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="information-outline" size={24} color="#979797" style={{padding:10}}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

 
        </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
       );
     }
   
   }
   
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
      tabs : state.tabs
    }
  }
  
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
      changeCounter : (index) => dispatch({type:'PAGE_CHANGED',payload: index}),
      toggleTour: () => dispatch({
          type: 'TOUR_OPENED'
      })
    }
  
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavBar);
```

I was thinking of putting this.props.start() inside a function and calling the function from another component.
How do I go about this?

Here is my App.js

```
export default class App extends Component { 
  render() { 
    return (
        <Provider store = {store}>
          <Routes />
        </Provider>
          

    ); 
  } 
}
```

The call for the NavBar is in Routes:

```
export default class Routes extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      
      <Router navBar={TopNavbar}> 
        <Scene key="root">
          ...
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is it a redux action ? (i mean the start function), and is it related to state or props from other components ? and if it is are all those components fetched from redux or are some of them local state to the component in which the function is defined ?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the function as a prop in the other component, for example in your render function you could do the following:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <YourComponent startTutorial={this.props.start}></YourComponent>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Then in `YourComponent` call `this.props.startTutorial();` from a button or any event.

** Update

So in your case you can do the following:

```
export default class App extends Component { 
    render() { 
      return (
          <Provider store = {store}>
            <Routes /*here*/ startTutorial={this.props.start} />
          </Provider>
      ); 
    } 
  }

  export default class Routes extends Component {

    /*here*/
    CTopNavbar = ({ children }) => (
        <TopNavbar startTutorial={this.props.startTutorial}>
          {children}
        </TopNavbar>
      );

    render() {
      return (
        
        <Router navBar={/*here*/CTopNavbar}> 
          <Scene key="root">
            ...
          </Scene>
        </Router>
      );
    }
  }
```

Then in NavBar run `this.props.startTutorial();` in your button.

Comment: Hey so the problem here is, these components are not related to each other. 
Like, YourComponent is not in the main component. Any ideas?

Comment: So I have 5 screens in my application. And I have a NavBar at the top with an information button. The screens are different components. The Navbar is a separate component. The button on the Navbar should basically trigger the start function on each screen depending on which screen is currently being viewed at the moment.

Comment: Hey I've added, please check.

Comment: Updated.Check Now.

Comment: Updated answer @Blake